# iptables setting output default to DROP

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

I have two servers: one web, one database.  The db server is on a private network.

I thought I needed to restrict the default OUTPUT on the web server to DROP and created OUTPUT rules to to ACCEPT However the web server can't access the db server when the OUTPUT default is set to DROP.  eth0 is public, eth1 is private. What am I missing here?

web server

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.131.181.201/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.131.181.201/32 -i eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rules are completely contradictory or redundant. You accept all outgoing traffic on eth0 but then add more specific rules. You use `-m tcp` while `-p tcp` already loads the module. You use `-m conntrack --ctstate` while you also write deprecated `-m state --state` etc ... This needs a big cleaning session.

But the main thing is you inverted sport and dport.

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Should be :

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

A fixed configuration should look like this :

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,465 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 465 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 10.131.181.201/32 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 10.131.181.201/32 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --sport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 465 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That certainly makes more sense.  Guess I was following too many tutorials. Is the line -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT needed if the only mysql traffic is to the db server on eth1?

Comment: @AllanD Then no, it's not. Removed it.

Comment: I the rules on the server now. The only thing that does not seem to be working is outbound SMTP.  Works if I flip the default OUTPUT to ACCEPT.

Comment: @AllanD That's not part of the original question, if you have another question post it as such with more context please.

Comment: The smtp is using tls on port 465, but fair enough on making it another question. Why do you have port 465 on both the INPUT with the multiport and the line afer it?

Comment: Also just tested ssh to the db server and it also is not working.

Comment: @AllanD The original question was as I guest it about contacting MySQL from your web server. Now it turns to be "*How to make all my rules work*" but with no context at all. I'm not a wizard, I can't guess what you want to do nor what service is running on the web server and what's not! Is the web server hosting SMTP or is it trying to contact another that hosts a SMTP service ? Add NEW state to the ssh rule for OUTPUT if that server must contact another one over SSH ... I don't really like that kind of big update once the answer is out that changes the OP to a completely different subject.

Comment: With what you provided I was able to get everything working, although I think I now have a few extra rules. I'll post a separate question for that. Thank you very much for sorting this out.